# How can we make below screenshot design in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

[image: Want to achieve a wave similar to the screenshot below with a progress bar on edge of the wave which is basically symbol for level achieved and the icons below wave will be some icon on the inner side of the waves]

Want to achieve a wave similar to the screenshot below with a progress bar on edge of the wave which is basically symbol for level achieved and the icons below wave will be some icon on the inner side of the waves